# how to fetch url from array and show image on table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Thanks in advance. I fetch image url in array.

```
myarray = { "http://www.abc.com/uploads/sarab.jpg", .... };
```

And now i dont know how to access the image in table view? Is there any example code for help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put this code in cellForRowAtindexPath  then it will work fine :

```
NSData *imageData= [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[myarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have to do this,

for fetching URL from Array Put this code in CellForRowAtIndexPath, this will help you..

```
NSString *str = [YOUR_ARR objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
```

First of all convert URL to NSData then assign then data to your Image..

```
NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
```

and after that

```
cell.imageView.image = image;
```

Happy coding..

Answer (score 0):

Below way, you can achieve this:

```
NSString *strImageUrl = [myarray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: strImageUrl];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]]; 
UIImageView *displayimage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[displayimage setImage:image];
```

Let me know in case of any difficulty.

Cheers

Comment: if i have array with some strings and image url then how i can fetch image url without using index number of array. Like myarray={"india",123654,"http://www.abc.com/uploads/sarab.jpg",..}

Comment: I think you have manage your Array very odd. You can get object from array then from string you can check that, if "www" or ".jpg, .png" exists in string. So it will be like URL and you can bind your Image.

Comment: My suggestion is create on NSObject class which has property like Title, Number, ImageUrl (India, 123456, abc.com/uploads.srarb.jpg). And add object of this class into your Array. So that, you will get object by using "Index.Row". Then you can use imageUrl like classObject.ImageUrl. And do the process. Hope you got the answer.